# getServletContext.getResourceAsStream returns null

Tags: java, servlets

I tried to create an Util class for controller classes calls. One thing gets me stuck for a bit while: in Util class,

there is a string variavle as

public static final String info = "/WEB-INF/classes/abc.properties";

There is a parser to get it:

```
String test = IOUtils.toString(config.getServletContext().getResourceAsStream(info));
```

// I have got the null value from this one but cannot get the why.

My question: I set the path for WEB with '/', but still the servlet still did not get it.  Your any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The classpath is what is inside `/classes`, not `/WEB-INF`.

Comment: Have you tried to open the .war file (e.g. using WinZip) to see if the file is actually there?

Comment: To Stotitrios, thank you for the hint. I will try this. But why /WEB-INF does not work?

Comment: To Andreas, I have not tried to check with your approach. I will be trying. Thank you.